# Tomcat logout session

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, tomcat9, httpsession

I have the problem, that the tomcat server logout every hour all active sessions, by a spring boot application.
Nothing happends, if i set the session time out in the web.xml file.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1080</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Also nothing happends, if i set the timeout in the application.yml file.

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 1080m
```

Is there any other option to increase the session timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. If i use spring boot version 2.3.8.RELEASE the session timeout config works. But if i use the newest version, then the session timeout not work.
If send a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

a little more information would have been helpful, BUT did you use Session?

in your Servlet you can Define for Session-Timeout:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60*14);
```

you get session from:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
```

after this you can check the Session Timeout on the Tomcat URL:

/manager/html

Comment: Is it possible, that the newest spring boot version 2.4.2 makes some problems? I have look at an old version of the my software module and i have used the spring boot version 2.2.6. After upgrading the spring boot version to 2.4.2 the software logout all http sessions.

Comment: sorry i am not using Spring boot, but try to create a Servlet without any Frameworks and test it again. if it works without any Framework so then its a Bug in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Which information do you need?
I use in the application following session config:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener
{
    @Override public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)
    {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(64800); // in seconds (18 hours)
    }

    @Override public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)
    {
    }
}
```

In the tomcat manager page the session time was set to 1080 minutes, but the value doesn't be use.
[tomcat manager page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CmX0.png)